# swiper.js multiple imgs per slide lazy loading not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

thanks for reading, I try to use swiper.js and it works fine with the lazy loading demo, but in the demo, there is only one image per slide, but I want to represent 4 imgs per slide, which turns out only the first img in each slide will show up.

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <!-- Required swiper-lazy class and image source specified in data-src attribute -->
            <img data-src="1.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
            <img data-src="2.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
            <img data-src="3.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
            <img data-src="4.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
            <img data-src="5.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
            <!-- Preloader image -->
            <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img data-src="2.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
            <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img data-src="3.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
            <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img data-src="4.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
            <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader swiper-lazy-preloader-white"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so, I am trying to read the jquery code in swiper.js, and due to my ability, I can not figure it out, tbh, I can not understand.

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

As long as I am using the same src with the ones in the slides after, it was lazy loaded too. After replacing all the data-srcs with diff ones, it works.

Thank, swiper.js

Comment: hi , i have a similar stuation, can you  explain how to add preloaders in the each slide.I have added lazing loading in the initalization of swiper                       preloadImages : false,
                lazyLoading : true,
                lazyLoadingOnTransitionStart : true,
                lazyLoadingInPrevNext : true,

Comment: rest of it am missing

Comment: what I was trying to say is that the first div in the divs with the class "swiper-slide" contains 5 imgs, while the 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg is also used in the other divs, as these imgs are lazy loaded in the other divs, they will not be loaded in the first div, as they are the same file, which should be lazy loaded by the swiper.js